# Python code to calculate distance between 2 zipcodes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and I would like to write a simple code for learning purposes

Lets say I have 2 zipcodes & I want to calculate the distance between them. how would I write code would prompt me to input both zipcodes and then output the distance(in miles)??

Ex:

**Zipcode1: 90210

Zipcode2: 11234

Output: 2,830 miles**

are there any certain libraries or packages that Ill need??

Comment: As a general recommendation, I don't recommend taking on a complex task that's going to involve learning GIS libraries if you're just starting in Python. Core Python (without any libraries) is going to give you plenty to work with in terms of arithmetic and I/O, so you'll likely have better luck starting with a simple calculator or a text-based game for learning purposes.

Comment: First, you need to get the `latitude, longitude` of each zip code. That you can do by opening google map and searching for the place, if you don't want to use any API services. Then you can apply `euclidian` distance as a starting point. If you want to go further you can check `haversine` distance.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Asking for software recommendations is *specifically* off topic.

Answer (score 1):

first get lat/lon ... then you can calculate haversine distance between 2 lat lon

this solution uses an API to retrieve the lat/lon ... there is no error handling for junk values ... additionally this is strictly as the crow flies ... it obviously does not tell you how far of a drive it is...

it uses the `requests` library for simplicity ... but im sure you could use urllib ... `math` is a builtin module

```
import requests
import math
 
def get_lat_lon(zip):
    uri = 'https://public.opendatasoft.com/api/records/1.0/search/?q={zip}&dataset=us-zip-code-latitude-and-longitude'
    return requests.get(uri.format(zip=zip)).json()["records"][0]['fields']['geopoint']

def rad(x):
  return x * math.pi / 180.0;


def getHaversineDistance(p1, p2):
  R = 6378137; # Earth’s mean radius in meter
  dLat = rad(p2[0] - p1[0]);
  dLong = rad(p2[1] - p1[1]);
  a = (math.sin(dLat / 2) * math.sin(dLat / 2) +
    math.cos(rad(p1[0])) * math.cos(rad(p2[0])) *
    math.sin(dLong / 2) * math.sin(dLong / 2))
  c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a))
  d = R * c #
  return d # // returns the distance in meter
def Meters2Miles(meters):
    return meters * 0.000621371

zip1 = input("Enter Zip1")
p1 = get_lat_lon(zip1)
zip2 = input("Enter Zip2")
p2 = get_lat_lon(zip2)
dist_meters = getHaversineDistance(p1,p2)
dist_miles = Meters2Miles(dist_meters)
print("There are about %f miles between zipcodes %s and %s"%(dist_miles,zip1,zip2))
```